# How to remove a single line in a .txt file using findstr Batch

Tags: batch-file

So I am trying to make my batch script delete an asset tag out a list after it has successfully completed its job and excited with an error code of 0 in this block of code.

```
FOR /F %%G IN (PingResults2.txt) DO (
    @psexec -s -w C:\ \\%%G -c -f "USMTCAPTURE.cmd"
    IF !errorlevel! equ 0 (
        echo %%G >> usmtdone.txt
        findstr /V %%G ToPingList2.txt > ToPingList2.txt
    )
)
```

as far as I  can tell that part of my code is working correctly but when it gets to this line in my loop it is just wiping out the whole file.

`findstr /V %%G ToPingList2.txt > ToPingList2.txt`

I tested, and to me it looks like it should work. `findstr /V %%G ToPingList2.txt` by it self call up all other line's of text in the file and when I tested `findstr /V %%G ToPingList2.txt >> ToPingList2.txt` it added all other lines in the file a second time. So why is `findstr /V %%G ToPingList2.txt > ToPingList2.txt` wiping the whole file clean?

Comment: Probably because you're trying to open `ToPingList2.txt` for writing when it's already open for reading.  Try outputting to a different file, then `move /y newfile ToPingList2.txt >NUL` after `findstr` has completed.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your destination file while findstr still is processing it as input. Since you are storing the entries in usmtdone.txt it's easy to remove them in one step following the for loop.

```
FOR /F %%G IN (PingResults2.txt) DO (
  @psexec -s -w C:\ \\%%G -c -f "USMTCAPTURE.cmd"
  IF !errorlevel! equ 0 (
    echo %%G >> usmtdone.txt
  )
)
findstr /V /G:usmtdone.txt ToPingList2.txt >ToPingList2.tmp
Move /Y ToPingList2.tmp ToPingList2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks LotPings for the quick response. I ended up doing code slightly different than your recommendation and its doing what I need it to so I figured I would post my own answer. Its seems that using a .tmp file to temporarily store the values and then moving it to the original is what I was missing.

```
FOR /F %%G IN (PingResults.txt) DO (
@psexec -s -w C:\ \\%%G -c -f "USMTCAPTURE.cmd"
IF !errorlevel! equ 0 (
echo %%G >> usmtdone.txt
findstr /V %%G ToPingList2.txt > ToPingList2.tmp
Move /Y ToPingList2.tmp ToPingList2.txt
)
)
```

Thanks for your help and suggestions! The code runs beautifully now.